# Get project information for all Revit models in my ACC account for 2020, 2021, 2022 and 2023

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

ACC has a lot of models, so I need to extract all Project Information Parameters for each model using the Autodesk Platform services, but all the tutorials I found focused on the parameters for the model elements.

It would be helpful if there is a sample of how to extract the project information parameters

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can access that information without downloading and processing each file. Once you have access to the project file, you can read its [`BasicFileInfo`](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/475edc09-cee7-6ff1-a0fa-4e427a56262a.htm). This information can also be read via the [Open Revit OLE Storage](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/open-revit-ole-storage.html), cf. also:

- [Open Revit OLE Storage](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/open-revit-ole-storage.html)
- [Basic File Info and RVT File Version](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/basic-file-info-and-rvt-file-version.html)
- [Determining RVT File Version Using Python](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/06/determining-rvt-file-version-using-python.html)
- [Access BIM360 Cloud Links, Thumbnail and Dynamo](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/06/accessing-bim360-cloud-links-thumbnail-and-dynamo.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you’re looking for the project address, project name, project number, client name, and so on in the RVT, we can do the following in viewer.

```js
async function searchAsync(model, text, attributeNames, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        model.search(text, resolve, reject, attributeNames, options);
    });
}

async function getBulkProperties2Async(dbIds, options, model) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        model.getBulkProperties2(
            dbIds,
            options,
            (result) => resolve(result),
            (error) => reject(error)
        );
    });
}


async function getProjectInfo(model, category = 'Project Information') {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const found = await searchAsync(model, category, ['Category'], { searchHidden: true });
        if (!found || found.length <= 0) return reject('Project Information not found');

        const result = await getBulkProperties2Async(found, { propFilter: ["Organization Name", "Organization Description", "Building Name", "Author", "Project Issue Date", "Project Status", "Client Name", "Project Address", "Project Name", "Project Number"] }, model);

        if (!result) return reject('Project Information not found');

        const data = result[0];
        return resolve(data);
    });
}

await getProjectInfo(model);
```

[image]
[image]